# Use serial port for real time signal logging in Matlab

Tags: matlab, real-time

I want to perform a real-time signal logging using MATLAB real-time windows target .How can I define an input block for real-time to use Serial Ports for receiving data from my own created data Data Acquisition Board .Every time I try to define one of COM ports I get this error :

Error reported by S-function 'rtwindi' in 'rt_test/Digital Input':
The board "Standard Devices Serial Port" has no Digital Input channels

Answer (score -1):

```
maybe this program help you

%% Vincent Chow
% chow@college.harvard.edu
%
% CS50 Project - Plots accelerometer data from serial port in real time
%
% Configuration:
% - Place Arduino USB cable in correct port
% - Close serial port if interrupted. Use fclose() and
% delete() in command window.
%
% Diagnostic tools:
% - instrfind returns open serial ports
%
% References:
% Template provided by http://billwaa.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/matlab-real-time-serial-data-logger/
%% Configuration
% set correct serial port address
port = '/dev/tty.usbmodem1411';
% variables for data and plotting
time = 0;
x_data = 0;
y_data = 0;
z_data = 0;
index = 0;
scroll_width = 10;
delay = 0.010;
min = 200;
max = 800;
loop = 0;
% initalize plots for x, y, and z data
graph1 = plot(time, x_data, 'm-');
hold on;
graph2 = plot(time, y_data, 'c-');
hold on;
graph3 = plot(time, z_data, 'g-');
% labeling axes
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Accelerometer Data');
legend('X Data', 'Y Data', 'Z Data');
title('ADXL345 Accelerometer Data');
% setup serial port
s = serial(port);
% since data is sent in a buffer of 10 bytes, our buffer is 2^10 in size
set(s, 'InputBufferSize', 1024);
% microcontroller controls data flow
set(s, 'FlowControl', 'hardware');
% chosen baudrate allows for realtime plotting without significant delay
set(s, 'BaudRate', 57600);
% no parity bit checking
set(s, 'Parity', 'none');
% set DataBits at 8 to allow transmission of binary data
set(s, 'DataBits', 8);
% set number of bits indicating end of data transmission to 1
set(s, 'StopBit', 1);
% set timeout to 10 seconds
set(s, 'Timeout', 10);
% open serial port as file for read access
fopen(s);
% start time
tic;
%% Plotting
% plots data while graphs are open
while ishandle(graph1)
% obtain data from serial port
stream = fscanf(s, '%f %f %f')';
% loops to plot every 10th data point - reduces delay
if (loop < 10)
loop = loop + 1;
continue;
elseif (loop == 10)
loop = 0;
end
% plot as long as data stream is not empty
if(~isempty(stream) && numel(stream) == 3)
% increment index
index = index + 1;
% increment time
time(index) = toc;
% take data from stream into respective data arrays
x_data(index) = stream(1, 1);
y_data(index) = stream(1, 2);
z_data(index) = stream(1, 3);
% plots data after initial start
% creates a scrolling window for data
if(scroll_width > 0)
selindex = time > time(index) - scroll_width;
set(graph1,'XData', time(selindex), 'YData', x_data(selindex));
set(graph2,'XData', time(selindex), 'YData', y_data(selindex));
set(graph3,'XData', time(selindex), 'YData', z_data(selindex));
axis([time(index) - scroll_width time(index) min max]);
else
% initializes plot
set(graph1,'XData', time, 'YData', x_data);
set(graph2, 'XData', time, 'YData', y_data);
set(graph3, 'XData', time, 'YData', z_data);
axis([0 time(index) min max]);
end
% delay to allow data to process
pause(delay);
end
end
% close serial port
fclose(s);
% delete serial port to allow plotting for subsequent sessions
delete(s);
```